# Two nested for each loops with objects and div selectors

Tags: jquery

I am struggling with two each loops. What I want to achieve is match corresponding object to correct each iteration.

There's my fiddle. In each div there's the same output, it should be 1,2,3 instead of 3,3,3.

```js
jQuery('.get-total-numbers').each(function(i, e) {
  var $el = jQuery(e);

  var json = '["1","2","3"]';
  var arr = $.parseJSON(json);

  myjson = json;
  json2 = JSON.parse(json);
  jQuery.each(json2, function(index, e) {
    console.log(e);
    $el.text(e);


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="get-total-numbers">

</div>

<div class="get-total-numbers">

</div>

<div class="get-total-numbers">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit @Barmar

Comment: You're not doing anything to match corresponding elements. The inner loop is just going through the whole array, replacing the current DIV with every item in the array. So when it's done, the DIV contains the last element of the array.

Comment: Well thought it was a good start. I want my output to be 1 for first div, 2 for second div etc.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a problem about JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
jQuery('.get-total-numbers').each(function(i, e) {
  var $el = jQuery(e);

  var json = '["1","2","3"]';
  var arr = $.parseJSON(json);

  myjson = json;
  json2 = JSON.parse(json);
  $el.text(json2[i]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="get-total-numbers">

</div>

<div class="get-total-numbers">

</div>

<div class="get-total-numbers">

</div>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Can you explain your solution and why changed what you changed?

Comment: What if I am dealing with more complex json and this json can be accessed by .each only? I mean, it's graph facebook where I am fetching data from multiple URLs. I cannot (or I don't know how) to fetch corresponding data from complex JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just overwriting each DIV with every element of the array, not just putting the matching element in each DIV.

You don't need the inner `jQuery.each` loop. If you want the corresponding element of the array, just use `arr[i]`.

```js
var json = '["1","2","3"]';
var arr = $.parseJSON(json);

jQuery('.get-total-numbers').each(function(i, e) {
  var $el = jQuery(e);
  $el.text(arr[i]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="get-total-numbers">

</div>

<div class="get-total-numbers">

</div>

<div class="get-total-numbers">

</div>
```